# Where is Al2O3 in Al2(SO4)3 coming from?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

let me know where is Al2O3 in Al2(SO4)3 containing from? as we know there is 17-18% Al2O3 in commonly Al2(SO4)3 product. 
is it because low convertion of reaction Al2O3 + 3H2SO4 = Al2(SO4)3 + 3H2O, or something?

if i using Al(OH)3 to convert Al2(SO4)3, 2Al(OH)3 + 3H2SO4 = Al2(SO4)3 + 6H2O, is it still happen 17-18% containing Al2O3 in Al2(SO3)3 because dehydration reaction of 2Al(OH)3 = Al2O3 + 3H2O?

Comment: Writing "Al2O3 in Al2(SO4)3" makes no sense; a chemical formula is used to denote the exact stoichiometric composition of a given compound, and these are no matryoshka dolls. You might want to re-formulate the question referring to the content of $\ce{Al2O3}$ in a certain ore/clinker/schist/clay/mineral by adding corresponding details.

Comment: @andselisk, most likely this is being taught in some South Asian school/university. It is an old way of quoting or reporting analysis or assay of salts etc.

Comment: @Fahmi Reza  Contains is not the proper term. Rather is equivalent.  100g of $\ce{Al2(SO4)3}$ is equivalent about 17g of $\ce{Al2O3}$, in ratio of their respective molar masses.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to very old analytical methods and analysis. In older times, many analyses were *reported* as oxides. This practice comes from gravimetric analysis. This practice continues today in fertilizers analysis and in some other industries. Coming to your question, there is **no** Al$_2$O$_3$ unit per se however the purity of aluminum sulfate may be quoted as aluminum oxide. Just do a simple mole calculation using the relation to determine the actual purity of aluminium sulfate. Just keep in mind, quoting percentage of oxides is purely historical, but you can easily do calculations as follows.

1 mol Al$_2$O$_3$   $\equiv$ 1 mol Al$_2$SO$_4$ $\equiv$ 1 mol Al$_2$SO$_4$. $x$H$_2$O

Comment: should be $\pu{1 mole }\ce{Al2O3} \equiv  \pu{1 mole }\ce{Al2(SO4)3} \equiv \pu{1 mole }\ce{Al2(SO4)3} \cdot x \ce{H2O}$

Comment: Is there a difference between a kilogram and a kg? "mol" is a symbol for amount of substance as one the SI base quantities. https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/units.html

Comment: In some complicated modern technologies, like cement, it gets even more distant from textbook chemistry. Tricalcium silicate, the major ingredient in cement, is Ca3SiO5 (alite), but it's usually written C3S, a shortcut. Then consider one of the products, ettringite: Ca6Al2(SO4)3(OH)12·26H2O https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ettringite. We simplify writing it by using three "languages": C3A + 3 CaSO4 → ettringite (cement shorthand, chemical symbols, and English words), and even the chemical symbol isn't exactly accurate, because the CaSO4 is usually a hemihydrate plus dihydrate.